# Kafka AdminClient seems to start twice

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I hope I'm able to explain this!

I'm starting a dockerized java spring boot application that will connect to a single dockerized Kafka instance.

To do this I have setup a link in the docker-compose file that will allow the application to connect to the kafka docker, named `kafka-cluster` on port `9092`.

When I start the both containers I get an error in the java application saying that it's unable to connect to KafkaAdmin:

`[AdminClient clientId=adminclient-2] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.`

But it's trying to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1.

Further up in the logs, I can see it started a connection to KafkaAdmin twice:
first:

```
2020-03-25 13:53:15.515  INFO 7 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig    : AdminClientConfig values: 
        bootstrap.servers = [kafka-cluster:9092]
        client.dns.lookup = default
        client.id = 
        connections.max.idle.ms = 300000
        <more properties>
```

and then again straight after (but on localhost):

```
2020-03-25 13:53:15.780  INFO 7 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig    : AdminClientConfig values: 
        bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
        client.dns.lookup = default
        client.id = 
        connections.max.idle.ms = 300000
        <more properties>
```

This is the config:

```
    @Bean
    public KafkaAdmin kafkaAdmin() {
        Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>();
        configs.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        return new KafkaAdmin(configs);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic sysCcukCdcAssetsCreate() {
        return new NewTopic(newPanelTopic, 1, (short) 1);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic sysCcukCdcAssetsUpdate() {
        return new NewTopic(updatedPanelTopic, 1, (short) 1);
    }
```

where `bootstrapServers` = `kafka-cluster:9092`

I can't see why it seems like KafkaAdmin has 2 sets of configs but it seems like it is causing the error.

Any guidance or suggestions massively appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So! This was a great rubber duck.

Turns out the `spring.kafka.bootstrap.servers` property hadn't been set in the properties file and it defaults to `localhost` setting this to `kafka-cluster:9092` fixed it :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've been stuck with this for  hours. spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers= saved me.

Comment: According to https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/ use dash instead of dot to split 'bootstrap' and 'servers'.